# Argparse Mutually exclusive groups not working on pair of positional and optional arguments

Tags: python-3.x, command-line-arguments, argparse

I have written a code where I want input file as command line argument. I want user to provide that in two ways:

1. using flag --input, ex:

   python3 prog.py --input A.cpp
2. simply without any flag

   python3 prog.py A.cpp

both should work as same.

I wrote a program for it using argparse.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import argparse
if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    input_file = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
    input_file.add_argument('inp',nargs='?',help='file name')
    input_file.add_argument('--input',dest='inp',help='file name')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    print(args)
```

It works fine for :

```
$ python3 prog.py A.cpp
Namespace(inp='A.cpp')
```

while not for :

```
$ python3 prog.py --input A.cpp
Namespace(inp=None)
```

I want both the ways to be mutually exclusive and their value to go to save destination ( like I did here`inp`). A person may skip both. means they are not required.

How could I achieve it?

Comment: That's a bad CLI. Just pick one way or the other, don't be wishy-washy about it.

Comment: Could you please suggest me some other way. I thought it as user friendly as earlier version of my program didn't supported flags so  users are used to `python3 prog.py A.cpp` , I want to add support of argparse without removing the old way

Comment: Did you try defining the flagged argument first?  Or using the same `dest` could be the problem.  The default for the positional might be overwriting the optional's value.  I don't think the mutually_exclusive group is giving problems.  But I'd have to run some test cases to be sure.

Comment: Ya I tried both the combinations by switching the position of both lines in code

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the common `dest`.  The default of the positional is overwriting the optional's value.

```
In [13]: p = argparse.ArgumentParser()
In [14]: a1 = p.add_argument('--foo')
In [15]: a2 = p.add_argument('bar', nargs='?', default='default')

In [16]: p.parse_args('xxx'.split())
Out[16]: Namespace(bar='xxx', foo=None)

In [17]: p.parse_args('--foo 1'.split())
Out[17]: Namespace(bar='default', foo='1')
```

Change so they share the `dest`:

```
In [18]: a1.dest = 'bar'
```

The optional is parsed, then the positional.  Since it is '?', the default value is place in the namespace, over writing the previous value

```
In [19]: p.parse_args('--foo 1'.split())
Out[19]: Namespace(bar='default')
```

Here the optional's value over writes the positional's:

```
In [20]: p.parse_args('xxx --foo 1'.split())
Out[20]: Namespace(bar='1')
```

Here the explicit positional value over writes the optionals:

```
In [21]: p.parse_args('--foo 1 xxx'.split())
Out[21]: Namespace(bar='xxx')
```

I realize the differences a subtle.  It has to do with how positionals and optionals are parsed (alternately), but also on how the `nargs='?'` positional is handled.

Comment: I agree with all you mentioned. it is working as it sould be. but my doubt is in `mutually_exclusive_groups`. atleast there should not be such `overriding` issues as both of the options are totally `mutually exclusive` so can't occur at one time then they must handle it way more carefully.

Comment: I am fine with `out[19]` it sould be there as they are not mutually exclusive, parser may think it like maybe person is not providing the value so give it `default value` but that should not be the case in `mutually exclusive` is persion has provided the value to `--input` it is quite sure that there is no chance of `inp` so it should not be given default value, WDYT @hpaulj

Comment: You are envisioning a much more sophisticated mutually exclusive mechanism  All it's testing is whether your user gave inputs to more than one Action in the group.  Nothing in `argparse` checks whether two or more actions write to the same `dest` or coordinates such writes.

Comment: I would keep the `dest` separate, and use a post-parsing test to combine them.  That logic should be pretty simple.

Comment: I thats a work around, I was just thinking there must be some `already provided` way to handle such situation. I think there should be one. writing own logic is `OK` for me, but it would have been cool if argparse did that work for me.